# Distinct after grouping by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below query as

```
WITH search_agg as(
SELECT user_id, count(search_id) as count_search
FROM search
WHERE date>current_date -interval '7 days'
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING count_search>10)

SELECT count (distinct user_id)
FROM search_agg
```

If am correct, I don't need distinct in my outer query since my group by takes care of that correct? or is it better practice to have distinct anyway? Thanks

Comment: correct , no need for distinct

Comment: Yes; by grouping you are already guaranteed 1 row per group, what do you think an additional *distinct* would gain you on rows that are already distinct?

Comment: `count(distinct user_id)` will perform worse, or ideally equal to just `count(*)`. Never use it unless there are duplicates. In this case there aren't any.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your need in this case there is no need for `distinct`. Because CTE already returns (distinct) group by user_id.

```
WITH search_agg as(
SELECT user_id, count(search_id) as count_search
FROM search
WHERE date>current_date -interval '7 days'
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING count_search>10)

SELECT count (user_id)
FROM search_agg;
```

If you have group by based on two or more columns then you need to use distinct to fetch unique rows.